# Merging DataFrame by an amount of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's suppose I have this kind of data frame:

```
            Count
Trip Date        
2014-01-01   5370
2014-01-02   8374
2014-01-03   1121
2014-01-04   2246
2014-01-05   2626
...           ...
2019-11-26  63410
2019-11-27  51121
2019-11-28  16090
2019-11-29  23095
2019-11-30  26389
```

How can I get a new df that looks like this:

```
             Count
Week number        
1             C1
2             C2
3             C3
4             C4
5             C4
...           ...
n-1         C(n-1)
n             Cn
```

where `Ci` is a sum of `Count` for each 7 days?

Comment: `df.resample('w').sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set your index to the date.

```
df.set_index(df["date"],inplace=True)
```

Then you just do day week or month like this

```
df.resample('D').sum()
df.resample('M').sum()
df.resample('Y').sum()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that when I do it in this way nothing happens, but when I type `df = df['count']...` I get a series as an output with no column `count`.

Comment: Is the dtype some kind of int for that col?

Comment: It appears I was combining old and new syntax. What about df without the ['count']

Comment: I mean how can I get a dataframe again after resampling?

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thanks!